# Accessing image data after the ngSrc gets resolved with an AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to write an angularjs directive to process EXIF metadata in an img that is already loaded.

My desired usage:

```
<img ng-src="{{url}}" my-exif-directive />
```

My directive looks pretty basic:

```
...
restrict: 'A',
link: function(scope, element) {       
    var exifData = EXIF.readFromBinaryFile(/* ... */);
    rotate(parseInt(exifData.Orientation || 1, 10), element);
}
...
```

Is there any way to tap into the image buffer?
When I debug it the `ng-src` parameter is still not resolved. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on other directives (e.g. `ng-repeat`), attributes and scope properties may not be interpolated in `link`. The one can also notice that `element.attr('attribute-name')` may not be interpolated, while `attrs.attributeName` will.

Generally it is safe to do this:

```
link: function(scope, element) {       
    $timeout(function () {
        ...
    });
}
```

If other directives don't use timeouts the similar way, directive's DOM is already there, as well as interpolated values.

Since there are bindings involved, and `src` may change with time, the proper way to handle it is:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {       
    attrs.$observe('src', function (attr) {
        if (!attr) return;
        ...
    });
}
```